# Coulomb's law and the continuous charge model in an infinite charged plane

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

The $E$-field of an infinite plane with a uniform charge density $\sigma$ has a constant magnitude equaling $2\pi\sigma$.

Now, this magnitude assumes a continuous charge model throughout the plane.

[image]

In reality, the plane is made up of discrete charges, which obey Coulomb's law.
[image]

Does the continuous model accurately describe what happens just on top of the plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The continuous model is an approximation which breaks down when you get too close to the discrete charges.